# saml - how to return group name of a user belong to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, aws-sso

I am trying to use aws sso - saml 2.0 to integrate with a tool and I am not sure how to return group name instead of group id.

The mapping I am using is memberOf --> ${user:groups}, and I can see group ids are returned, however, the tool integration is expecting group name so it can do group mapping when the user is sign-in to the app.

I wonder if it is possible to configure so the saml will send human readable group names?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find some way to get group names?

Comment: it is not supported by aws sso. I could only get group ids